# Drupal 9 webform issue with file element

Tags: drupal, webforms

I have a problem with which I have been struggling for several days. So i have an webform with a file element inside and on submit button the page is refreshing instead of submitting the form. If i remove the file element the form work corectly.

Someone have the same problem?

Comment: If the page is refreshing, then you have a post-back, right? And a webform is a "form" page. So, it not clear how a page  can re-fresh without a post-back occurring?

Comment: I partially found the problem. I see that the File input in Drupal comes with an 'Upload' button that have type="submit". I hide the upload button and now when i hit the main submit button effectively drupal is trying to upload the file instead of submitting the form. Now my answer is, how i can correctly remove that upload button and submitting the file at the same time with the form?